# Nested dictionary of namedtuples to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, namedtuple

I have namedtuples defined as follows:

```
In[37]: from collections import namedtuple
        Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

The nested dictionary has the following format:

```
In[38]: d
Out[38]: 
{1: {None: {1: Point(x=1.0, y=5.0), 2: Point(x=4.0, y=8.0)}},
2: {None: {1: Point(x=45324.0, y=24338.0), 2: Point(x=45.0, y=38.0)}}}
```

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from the dictionary d without having to do for loops.

I have succeeded in creating the dataframe from a subset of the dictionary by doing this:

```
In[40]: df=pd.DataFrame(d[1][None].values())

In[41]: df

Out[41]: 
   x  y
0  1  5
1  4  8
```

But i want to be able to create the dataframe from the entire dictionary.

I want the dataframe to output the following (i am using multi index notation):

```
In[42]: df
Out[42]:
Subcase Step ID  x       y
1       None 1   1.0     5.0
             2   4.0     8.0
2       None 1   45324.0 24338.0
             2   45.0    38.0
```

The from_dict method of DataFrame, only supports up to two levels of nesting, so i was not able to use it. I am also considering modifying the structure of the d dictionary to achieve my goal. Furthermore, maybe it does not have to be a dictionary.

Thank you.

Comment: You say it doesn't have to be a dict - what's the source of the data in the dict?  Or were you referring to transforming the dict into an intermediate structure before turning it into a dataframe?

Comment: The source of the data is from a binary file. It is transformed to a dict for ease of access and fast querying. It would ideally remain a dict. What i was trying to say is that i could alter the code that changes the binary to a dict and use something that is more friendly to pandas. Transforming the dict seems to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to flatten the keys into a tuple (tested using pandas 0.18.1):

```
In [5]: from collections import namedtuple

In [6]: Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

In [11]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [14]: d=OrderedDict()

In [15]: d[(1,None,1)]=Point(x=1.0, y=5.0)

In [16]: d[(1,None,2)]=Point(x=4.0, y=8.0)

In [17]: d[(2,None,1)]=Point(x=45324.0, y=24338.0)

In [18]: d[(2,None,2)]=Point(x=45.0, y=38.0)
```

Finally,

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: df=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['Subcase','Step','ID']))


In [9]:df
Out[9]: 
                       x        y
Subcase Step ID                  
1       NaN  1       1.0      5.0
             2       4.0      8.0
2       NaN  1   45324.0  24338.0
             2      45.0     38.0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already several answers to similar questions on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988131/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe-where-dictionary-keys-are-column-label), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611782/pandas-dataframe-from-nested-dictionary)). These solutions can be adapted to this problem as well. However, none of them is really general to be run on an arbitrary dict. So I decided to write something more universal.

This is a function that can be run on any dict. The dict has to have the same number of levels (depth) at any of its elements, otherwise it will most probably raise.

```
def frame_from_dict(dic, depth=None, **kwargs):
    def get_dict_depth(dic):
        if not isinstance(dic, dict):
            return 0
        for v in dic.values():
            return get_dict_depth(v) + 1

    if depth is None:
        depth = get_dict_depth(dic)

    if depth == 0:
        return pd.Series(dic)
    elif depth > 0:
        keys = []
        vals = []
        for k, v in dic.items():
            keys.append(k)
            vals.append(frame_from_dict(v, depth - 1))
        try:
            keys = sorted(keys)
        except TypeError:
            # unorderable types
            pass
        return pd.concat(vals, axis=1, keys=keys, **kwargs)

    raise ValueError("depth should be a nonnegative integer or None")
```

I sacrificed a namedtuple case from this question for the generality. But it can be tweaked if needed.

In this particular case, it can be applied as follows:

```
df = frame_from_dict(d, names=['Subcase', 'Step', 'ID']).T
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
df
Out[115]: 
                       x        y
Subcase Step ID                  
1       NaN  1       1.0      5.0
             2       4.0      8.0
2       NaN  1   45324.0  24338.0
             2      45.0     38.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked like a charm. I was aware of this solution but i was specifically trying to avoid using for loops, since i can control what the definition of the dictionary. I decided to flatten the keys into a tuple. See solution below

Comment: @snowleopard I see. Do you have a general method of flattening keys of a nested dictionary to tuples? I thought this was the crux of the problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but i am creating the dictionary from a binary file, so i can control how the dictionary is defined.

Comment: Ah, all right. Creating tuples directly is then a better approach.