# Creating an easy way to read a JSON object saved in a complex, nested python dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a JSON object being pulled from an API. I pulled the JSON data into a python dictionary. I'm now finding it difficult to extract data from the dictionary because it is nested and has sublists and sub-dictionaries. To better understand the nature of the data pulled, I tried the below:

```
url = "https://api.xyz.com/v11/api.json?KEY=abc&LOOKUP=bbb"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print (type(data))
print(data.keys())
print (type(data['Results']))
print (len(data['Results']))
print (type(data['Results'][0]))
print (data['Results'][0].keys())
print (type(data['Results'][0]['Result']))
print ((data['Results'][0]['Result'].keys()))
print (type((data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'])))
print (len((data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'])))
print (type((data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0])))
print ((data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0].keys()))
print (type(data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0]['Technologies']))
print (len(data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0]['Technologies']))
print ((data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0]['Technologies'][8].keys()))
print (data['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths'][0]['Technologies'][8]['Tag'])
```

From the above, I got the following output:

```
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['Results', 'Errors'])
<class 'list'>
1
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['Lookup', 'LastIndexed', 'FirstIndexed', 'Meta', 'Result'])
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['Paths', 'IsDB', 'Spend'])
<class 'list'>
9
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['LastIndexed', 'Technologies', 'Domain', 'SubDomain', 'FirstIndexed', 'Url'])
<class 'list'>
77
dict_keys(['FirstDetected', 'Name', 'LastDetected', 'Categories', 'Description', 'IsPremium', 'Tag', 'Link'])
cdn
```

From other iterations of this, I know that depending on the list item I choose after 'Paths', I can get a varying list length for 'Technologies' ranging from 5 -100. I'm specifically interested in getting a list of all technologies for which the 'Tag' == A. I want to be able to create a table with all the upper level information for all entries that have the 'Tag' == A. Ideally, I want to get this info in a CSV file. I've looked at [Pandas dataframe from nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611782/pandas-dataframe-from-nested-dictionary) and [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python?rq=1) and [Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary) but **get confused  when it comes to accessing the list (specially after 'Paths').**

So far, the code I have is a simple data dump into a CSV which is not useful at all since all of the data goes into one cell and is not at all usable.

Comment: Can you show us the first two elements of your JSON file ?

Comment: You could perform a FlatDict if that helps https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flatdict and iterate through a flattened out dictionary which helps converting to a CSV format

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do this. Code below.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas

domaindict = {}
tech_info = {}
tag = 'mobile'

'''For every domain, pulls the api response, stores in dictionary, and gets dataframe
with technology info by calling the get_paths and set_df functions'''

def get_info(d):
    url = "https://api.xyz.com/v11/api.json?KEY=abc&LOOKUP={}".format(d)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    domaindict[d] = data
    paths = get_paths(d)
    final_info = set_df(paths)
    return final_info

'''Gets the list of paths for a domain'''        
def get_paths(d):
    paths = domaindict[d]['Results'][0]['Result']['Paths']
    return paths

'''Sets up dataframe to get info at the technology level. Loops through the technology list and path lists.'''
def set_df(paths):
    df_m = pandas.DataFrame({'Domain':[],'Url':[],'Subdomain':[],'Technology Name':[],'Technology Description':[],'Technology Tag':[]})
    for path in paths:
        domain_name = path['Domain']
        url = path['Url']
        subdomain = path['SubDomain']
        techs = path['Technologies']
        for tech in techs: 
            tech_name = tech['Name']
            tech_desc = tech['Description']
            tech_tag = tech['Tag']
            df =  pandas.DataFrame({'Domain':[domain_name], 'Url':[url], 'Subdomain':[subdomain], 
                                    'Technology Name':[tech_name],
                                     'Technology Description': [tech_desc],
                                     'Technology Tag': [tech_tag]})
            df_m = df_m.append(df)
        return df_m


'''loops through the csv file with list of domain names, calls the get_info function and saves dataframe with technology info for
every domain in one file'''

read_domains = pandas.read_excel('domain.xlsx', header = None)
df_f = pandas.DataFrame()
for d in read_domains.values: 
    print(d[0])
    df_i = get_info(d[0])
    df_f = df_f.append(df_i)


with pandas.ExcelWriter('mobile.xlsx') as w:
    df_f.to_excel(w,'mobile')
```